# VBA Sorting Desc across multiple sheets in one code snippet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have the code below which works on an individual basis, but if I try to run multiple sheets at once, it generates the **Run-time error '1004':  Unable to get the CurrentRegion property of the Range class** error.

Not an expert here, but I think this has something to do with CurrentRegion in the code, and also seems to have something to do with whether or not the columns are able to be filtered.

Any thoughts or slick way to fix this?

```
Sub SorterPorter()


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("R1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("D").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

should be

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=.Range("I1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

otherwise the "key" range is scoped to the ActiveSheet, which may not be the sheet where you want to sort.